# Word Choice: When something negative happens that changes your perspective for the better

Tags: word-choice

Examples:
1.Today I got in a car accident, but I now value life more.
2. Today, I stubbed my toe, but looked down and found my wife's wedding ring we thought was lost.

This concept is called the `blank` effect.  Or, I was struck by the `blank` of this event that made me see the reality of life in a different way.

I'm thinking `unforeseen benefit`, or `unexpected surprise` but they are just both too boring, and I would like one word that captures it.  I would like something that more accurately captures the perspective-shift aspect of the event.

Comment: Pegasus effect.

Comment: Blessing in disguise.

Comment: @JohnSmithers Why Pegasus?

Comment: Brian, what is your question, exactly? How will you decide which answer is the "correct" one to that question? If you're simply looking for one word, I don't think this question is particularly answerable, as that would be purely a matter of opinion.

Comment: @NeilFein: Hmmm... I see what you are saying.  Asking for one word probably wasn't the way to go.  Is it possible to make word choice questions that has a non-opinionated answer?  I'm thinking I'll pick the answer that most closely captured the concept I'm looking for, right?  Is the problem that I tried for one word, instead of a phrase?

Comment: One of the problems is that this is more about language and words and not really about writing at all. Another is that the question is more of a word game than a question, and people are pretty much just guessing at the answer. I'm afraid this question is better suited to a discussion forum than a Stack Exchange Q&A site like this. I'm going to close this, but you might have better luck on [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) or on [reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue](http://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue).

Answer (score 2):

I would call it the Lemonade Effect. As in, "when life gives you lemons, make..."

Comment: May also be the 'my life sucked turn-point.' But I can't decide whether this Q should be constrained to 'small happenings/a harm hiding good' moments or broadened to 'eye opener/life saver' situations too...

Comment: @Mussri:  I having trouble deciding between your two options also.  I am looking for `eye opener`, but not so big as `life saver`, and leaning toward `harm hiding good`

Comment: "Harm hiding good" is "Every cloud has a silver lining." There's also a somewhat relevant dirty joke with the punchline "...there's gotta be a pony in here somewhere!" but it's a little off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something's **"silver lining".**

Although I don't think this is quite what you're looking for, you could say it was a "near-death experience" or "out-of-body experience" because most people associate coming back from "near-death with a refreshed view or awakening.